# Binomial Distribution Graph from the Equation

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot a normal distribution with p=0.5 and n=10. I entered this in Mathematica:

```
Ph=0.5;
Ntot=10;
ListPlot[Table[Ph^(Nh)*(1 - Ph)^(Ntot - Nh)*Ntot!/((Nh!*(10 - Nh)!)), {Nh, 0, 10}]]
```

It plots the y values for x=1 to x=11. How can I plot it from x=0 to x=10?

Comment: `ListPlot[Table[{Nh, 
   Ph^(Nh)*(1 - Ph)^(Ntot - Nh)*Ntot!/((Nh!*(10 - Nh)!))}, {Nh, 0, 10}]]`

Comment: `ListPlot` plots a set like `{y1,y2,y3,...}` counting the elements from 1, e.g. consider `ListPlot[Table[x, {x, 10, 15}]]`. You need to explicitly make a set of pairs `{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...}`, so: `ListPlot[Table[{Nh, 
   Ph^(Nh)*(1 - Ph)^(Ntot - Nh)*Ntot!/((Nh!*(10 - Nh)!))}, {Nh, 0, 
   10}]]`

Answer (score 7):

Apart from adding the x value to the list of points, or using `DataRange` to specify the x-range one could also use `DiscretePlot`, which is made for these kinds of plots:

```
DiscretePlot[PDF[BinomialDistribution[Ntot, Ph], x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

```
Ph = 0.5;
Ntot = 10;
ListPlot[Table[{Nh, Ph^(Nh)*(1 - Ph)^(Ntot - Nh)*Ntot!/((Nh!*(10 - Nh)!))}, {Nh, 0, 10}]]
```

[image: Out]

or

```
ListPlot[
 Table[Ph^(Nh)*(1 - Ph)^(Ntot - Nh)*Ntot!/((Nh!*(10 - Nh)!)), {Nh, 0, 10}]
 , DataRange -> {0, 10}]
```

[image: Out2]

Answer (score 5):

The [binomial distribution](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinomialDistribution.html) is built in

```
With[{Ph = 1/2, Ntot = 10},
 DiscretePlot[
  PDF[
   BinomialDistribution[Ntot, Ph],
   Nh],
  {Nh, 0, Ntot}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Instead writing the factorials, one can use `Binomial[n,k]`, ${n\choose k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$:

```
ListPlot[Table[{Nh, 
   Ph^Nh (1 - Ph)^(Ntot - Nh) Binomial[Ntot, Nh]},
      {Nh, Range[0, Ntot]}], Frame -> True]
```

[image]